# Gamma detector Resolution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, gamma-rays

I read that the resolution of the gamma-detector $\frac{∆E}E∝E^{-\frac12}$

But it didn't mention the derivation, I am interested in the derivation, any hint will be appreciated.

Best Wishes

Rashed Aljasmi

Comment: Your first equation appears to be incomplete as $E/E$ is just unity and cannot be proportional to $E^{-1/2}$

Comment: Either a solid state (e.g. germanium) or scintillation detector spit out either a charge pulse or a photon pulse to be quantified and detected. The number of charges/photons created are proportional to the energy of the gamma. As a first estimate, the error in counting $n$ is $\sqrt n$.

Comment: @Triatticus there's a constant of propotion

Comment: What I'm saying, is as it's written, the equation is incorrect, if there is an additional variable it should be put in the equation. That is you need to correct your MathJaX so the equation looks like wherever you got it from.